# visual studio and exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

How can I see quick what exceptions a method throws. for ex I write: Int32.Parse(mystring). and when I write catch(... intelisense to give me the ex list or something. Or even a list of exceptions shown when I move the mouse over the method would be ok.

Comment: try again, hover cursor over `Parse` and you'll see the list of exceptions (at least in VS 2008 and 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Object Browser (View/Object Browser) in Visual Studio.

Main advantage of using the object browser is it's easier to see what Exceptions are thrown for each overloaded method compared to relying on intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

you'll see it on the intellisense of the Parse function.

you'll get something like this

```
Int32.Parse(              Parse(String objet) throws FooException.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
//do some operation
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
String message = ex.Message;
String innerException = ex.InnerException;

//put the values in a message box or log to file
}
```